# react-native-ble-plx: BLE Scanning in iOS Background & Suspended mode

Tags: react-native, bluetooth

Context
IOS Background and suspended mode

Library version: react-native-ble-plx 1.0.3
Platform: iOS.
Platform logs (XCode)

Expected Behavior
When the app is even in the background or suspended mode of ios, the callback of the startDeviceScan gets invoked.

Current Behavior
When the app is in the background or suspended mode of ios, the callback of the startDeviceScan never gets invoked. I assume there is never discovery event found yet, according to the apple ble doc. Is it possible to configure the 'startDeviceScan' to make the app scan in the background and suspended mode?

Answer (score 0):

After a few research, I find something helpful related with ble scanning in ios background & suspend mode.

1.) Scanning is throttled down when iOS devices are in the background.

While scanning in the foreground will likely immediately discover a device advertising next to it, discovery in the background can take up to ~60 times longer. The iOS system makes no assumptions that the user would prefer one app to have better Bluetooth functionality than another (or that only one app wants to use it). And since it is shared functionality, they want users to have a uniform experience across apps. You should check out the technical specifications regarding Advertising and Scanning intervals to get a better idea of what Apple has to do under the covers.

2.) Your devices may have already discovered each other before entering the background.

We must remember that Apple disables the CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKeyscanning flag when we enter the background. Since you're not even specifying this flag, it defaults to NO anyways. So if they've even seen each other once, you will not get another callback when they are in the background.

3.) Respect the Limits of Advertising Data

Although advertising packets in general can hold a variety of information about the peripheral device, you may advertise only your device’s local name and the UUIDs of any services you want to advertise.  There are also limits as to how much space you can use when advertising data. When your app is in the foreground, it can use up to 28 bytes of space in the initial advertisement data for any combination of the two supported advertising data keys. If this space is used up, there are an additional 10 bytes of space in the scan response that can be used only for the local name. Any service UUIDs that do not fit in the allotted space are added to a special “overflow” area; they can be discovered only by an iOS device that is explicitly scanning for them. While your app is in the background, the local name is not advertised and all service UUIDs are place in the overflow area.